# Flask-Login check if user is authenticated without decorator

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

From the Flask-Login docs, it's described how a user of the system can require an authenticated User-model to access a method utilising the decorator syntax:

```
from flask_login import login_required    

@app.route("/settings")
@login_required
def settings():
    pass
```

Now that's all well and good, but I want to be able to examine if the user is authenticated in a method, something like this:

```
@app.route('/main/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
main_route():
    if request.method == 'GET':
         if user_is_authenticated():    #Do the authentication here
             #load authenticated /main/ html template etc.
             pass
         else:
             #load unauthenticated /main/ html template etc.
             pass
    ...
```

The reason for this, is because it factorises the GET and POST requests rather than duplicating routes for authenticated users and unauthenticated users.
How can I do this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

This is very simple in flask:

```
from flask_login import current_user

@app.route(...)
def main_route():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
         return render_template("main_for_user.html")
    else:
         return render_template("main_for_anonymous.html")
```

See [the documentation on anonymous users](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#anonymous-users).

Comment: In later versions of the login manager module `is_authenticated` is an attribute rather than a method so you should use `if current_user.is_authenticated:`

Comment: This still works in 2019.  Thanks for the simple answer.  :)

Answer (score 2):

You could refer to the example [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/views/).

When the user has logged in, set `session['logged_in']=True`. At the same time, you can use Flask-login API to do some configurations in case that you want to use its functionality.
When you want to check whether the user has logged in manually rather than use the Flask-login API, then check the value of `session['logged_in']`.

Comment: session from the flask library is not available across blueprints. That's why I decided against using it.

Comment: @SebastianNielsen, the global `g` object is available across blueprints for the duration of the request. You can combine it with `flask.session`. From the [Flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/api/#flask.g): "This is a good place to store resources during a request. For example, a before_request function could load a user object from a session id, then set g.user to be used in the view function."